# mysql 8.0, how to recovery table strutcure from ibd files?

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

Backgroud: I get timemachine backups files from a macbook. Now I don't have macbook. I get mysql data folder from backups files. Now I want to recovery database table structure(I don't mind the store datas, I just want the table structure) from mysql data folder on a windows10 computer.

I try some methods: copy the database folder and ibdata1 to destination mysql server data folder. Then run the mysql and it runs successfully. But when I open workbench, the added database is not in the scheme lists.

Addtion: both the source and destination mysql version are 8.0. I don't know the original database table structure.

Comment: look at the mysql error log. A backup is only a backup if tested. Best guess is a full datadir and not bits and pieces. AFAIK timemachine isn't an instantaneous copy and therefore totally unsuitable for an active database. Congratulations on your mac escape.

Comment: @danblack it is a sad story, thank you